# How to pass a model property to a javascript function in JSP which itself returns a value

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, spring-mvc

I have to format the date I have received from the controller [Spring] in the jsp page itself. 

here's the JSP file :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<script
src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/js/custom/customer.js">/script>
</head>
<body>

                <table id="success-story">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th width="5%">Sl#</th>
                            <th width="50%">Description</th>
                            <th width="10%">Status</th>
                            <th width="30%">Created on</th>
                            <th width="5%">Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <c:forEach items="${customer.rfqs}" var="v" varStatus="count">
                            <tr>
                                <td>${count.count}</td>
                                <td>${v.description}</td>
                                <td>${v.status}</td>
                                <td>$v.createdTs</td>
                                <td align="center">
                                   <a href="#" onclick="view(${v.requestId})"> view</a>
                                   <a href="#" onclick="edit(${v.requestId})">edit</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

  </body>
 </html>'
```

The  ${v.createdTS} returns a TimeStamp of the form YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS

Now i have to convert this Timestamp into this format DD:MM:YYYY
But it is to be done at frond end only while populating the row, how can it be done ?

    
I have tried many possible solutions but none of them worked, here's the function i have in JS file

customer.js :

```
function formatDate(date) {
  var monthNames = [
    "Jan", "Feb", "Mar",
    "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul",
    "Aug", "Sep", "Oct",
    "Nov", "Dec"
  ];

  var day = date.getDate();
  var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  return day + ' ' + monthNames[monthIndex] + ' ' + year;
}
```

Can i use this function in some way   or any other alternative would work for me. I need just the conversion.

Advance thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If createdTs property is a Date Object - you can use [fmt tag](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_format_formatdate_tag.htm).

```
<fmt:formatDate pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd" value = "${v.createdTs}" />
```

If it is of String type, you may do the formating at server side.

Comment: Remember also to specify the taglib uri like this `<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>`